# Kendo MVVM autocomplete not loading items

Tags: jquery, mvvm, autocomplete, asmx, kendo-ui

I am getting the response back from the server, and everything looks good, but for some reason items are not been displayed for the autocomplete widget. If someone could point out what I'm doing wrong, that would be much appreciated.

Response from the server when I type something in the autocomplete box:

```
{"d":[{"__type":"BlaBla.Services.svcMedication+Medication","MedicationId":0,"Name":"Name0"},{"__type":"BlaBla.Services.svcMedication+Medication","MedicationId":1,"Name":"Name1"},{"__type":"BlaBla.Services.svcMedication+Medication","MedicationId":2,"Name":"Name2"},{"__type":"BlaBla.Services.svcMedication+Medication","MedicationId":3,"Name":"Name3"},{"__type":"BlaBla.Services.svcMedication+Medication","MedicationId":4,"Name":"Name4"},{"__type":"BlaBla.Services.svcMedication+Medication","MedicationId":5,"Name":"Name5"},{"__type":"BlaBla.Services.svcMedication+Medication","MedicationId":6,"Name":"Name6"},{"__type":"BlaBla.Services.svcMedication+Medication","MedicationId":7,"Name":"Name7"},{"__type":"BlaBla.Services.svcMedication+Medication","MedicationId":8,"Name":"Name8"},{"__type":"BlaBla.Services.svcMedication+Medication","MedicationId":9,"Name":"Name9"},{"__type":"BlaBla.Services.svcMedication+Medication","MedicationId":10,"Name":"Name10"},{"__type":"BlaBla.Services.svcMedication+Medication","MedicationId":11,"Name":"Name11"},{"__type":"BlaBla.Services.svcMedication+Medication","MedicationId":12,"Name":"Name12"},{"__type":"BlaBla.Services.svcMedication+Medication","MedicationId":13,"Name":"Name13"},{"__type":"BlaBla.Services.svcMedication+Medication","MedicationId":14,"Name":"Name14"},{"__type":"BlaBla.Services.svcMedication+Medication","MedicationId":15,"Name":"Name15"},{"__type":"BlaBla.Services.svcMedication+Medication","MedicationId":16,"Name":"Name16"},{"__type":"BlaBla.Services.svcMedication+Medication","MedicationId":17,"Name":"Name17"},{"__type":"BlaBla.Services.svcMedication+Medication","MedicationId":18,"Name":"Name18"},{"__type":"BlaBla.Services.svcMedication+Medication","MedicationId":19,"Name":"Name19"}]}
```

Autocomplete definition and binding

```
<input id="acMedications" data-role="autocomplete" data-text-field="Name" data-bind="source: dsMedication, value: SelectedMedication"
        style="width: 400px;" placeholder="Enter value..." />
```

ViewModel and DataSource definition

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        var viewModel = kendo.observable({
            dsMedication: new kendo.data.DataSource({
                transport: {
                    read: {
                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "../Services/svcMedication.asmx/SearchMedication",
                        dataType: "json",
                        cache: false
                    },
                    update: {
                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "../Services/svcMedication.asmx/SaveMedication",
                        dataType: "json",
                        cache: false
                    },
                    destroy: {
                        url: "../Services/svcMedication.asmx/DeleteMedication",
                        type: "DELETE",
                        dataType: "json",
                        cache: false
                    },
                    create: {
                        url: "../Services/svcMedication.asmx/SaveMedication",
                        type: "PUT",
                        cache: false
                    },
                    parameterMap: function(options, operation) {
                        if (operation !== "read" && options.models) {
                            return {
                                models: kendo.stringify(options.models)
                            };
                        }
                        options.MedicationParam = $('#acMedications').val();
                        return kendo.stringify(options);
                    }
                },
                batch: true,
                schema: {
                    data: "d",
                    model: {
                        id: "MedicationId",
                        fields: {
                            MedicationId: {
                                type: "number"
                            },
                            Name: {
                                type: "text"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },
                success: function(data) {
                    alert(data);
                }
            }),
            SelectedMedication: null,
            HasChanges: false,
            save: function() {
                this.dsMedication.sync();
                this.set("HasChanges", false);
            },
            remove: function() {
                if (confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this record?")) {
                    this.dsMedication.remove(this.SelectedMedication);
                    this.set("SelectedMedication", this.dsMedication.view()[0]);
                    this.change();
                }
            },
            showForm: function() {
                return this.get("SelectedMedication") !== null;
            },
            change: function() {
                this.set("HasChanges", true);
            }
        });

        kendo.bind($("#fmMedication"), viewModel);
    });
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Tried to reproduce it to no avail. Here is the code that I tried:

```
var viewModel = kendo.observable({
            dsMedication: new kendo.data.DataSource({
                transport: {
                  read: function(options) {
                    options.success(
{"d":[{"__type":"BlaBla.Services.svcMedication+Medication","MedicationId":0,"Name":"Name0"},{"__type":"BlaBla.Services.svcMedication+Medication","MedicationId":1,"Name":"Name1"},{"__type":"BlaBla.Services.svcMedication+Medication","MedicationId":2,"Name":"Name2"},{"__type":"BlaBla.Services.svcMedication+Medication","MedicationId":3,"Name":"Name3"},{"__type":"BlaBla.Services.svcMedication+Medication","MedicationId":4,"Name":"Name4"},{"__type":"BlaBla.Services.svcMedication+Medication","MedicationId":5,"Name":"Name5"},{"__type":"BlaBla.Services.svcMedication+Medication","MedicationId":6,"Name":"Name6"},{"__type":"BlaBla.Services.svcMedication+Medication","MedicationId":7,"Name":"Name7"},{"__type":"BlaBla.Services.svcMedication+Medication","MedicationId":8,"Name":"Name8"},{"__type":"BlaBla.Services.svcMedication+Medication","MedicationId":9,"Name":"Name9"},{"__type":"BlaBla.Services.svcMedication+Medication","MedicationId":10,"Name":"Name10"},{"__type":"BlaBla.Services.svcMedication+Medication","MedicationId":11,"Name":"Name11"},{"__type":"BlaBla.Services.svcMedication+Medication","MedicationId":12,"Name":"Name12"},{"__type":"BlaBla.Services.svcMedication+Medication","MedicationId":13,"Name":"Name13"},{"__type":"BlaBla.Services.svcMedication+Medication","MedicationId":14,"Name":"Name14"},{"__type":"BlaBla.Services.svcMedication+Medication","MedicationId":15,"Name":"Name15"},{"__type":"BlaBla.Services.svcMedication+Medication","MedicationId":16,"Name":"Name16"},{"__type":"BlaBla.Services.svcMedication+Medication","MedicationId":17,"Name":"Name17"},{"__type":"BlaBla.Services.svcMedication+Medication","MedicationId":18,"Name":"Name18"},{"__type":"BlaBla.Services.svcMedication+Medication","MedicationId":19,"Name":"Name19"}]}                    
                    );
                  }
                },
                batch: true,
                schema: {
                    data: "d",
                    model: {
                        id: "MedicationId",
                        fields: {
                            MedicationId: {
                                type: "number"
                            },
                            Name: {
                                type: "text"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }),
            SelectedMedication: null
        });

kendo.bind(document.body, viewModel);
```

And here is a live demo: http://jsbin.com/ahiyay/2/edit

Answer (score 0):

Correct code that works:

> var viewModel = kendo.observable({
>               dataSource: new kendo.data.DataSource({
>                   data: [{"_*type":"BlaBla.Services.svcMedication+Medication","MedicationId":0,"Name":"Name0"},{"*_type":"BlaBla.Services.svcMedication+Medication","MedicationId":1,"Name":"Name1"},{"_*type":"BlaBla.Services.svcMedication+Medication","MedicationId":2,"Name":"Name2"},{"*_type":"BlaBla.Services.svcMedication+Medication","MedicationId":3,"Name":"Name3"},{"_*type":"BlaBla.Services.svcMedication+Medication","MedicationId":4,"Name":"Name4"},{"*_type":"BlaBla.Services.svcMedication+Medication","MedicationId":5,"Name":"Name5"},{"_*type":"BlaBla.Services.svcMedication+Medication","MedicationId":6,"Name":"Name6"},{"*_type":"BlaBla.Services.svcMedication+Medication","MedicationId":7,"Name":"Name7"},{"_*type":"BlaBla.Services.svcMedication+Medication","MedicationId":8,"Name":"Name8"},{"*_type":"BlaBla.Services.svcMedication+Medication","MedicationId":9,"Name":"Name9"},{"_*type":"BlaBla.Services.svcMedication+Medication","MedicationId":10,"Name":"Name10"},{"*_type":"BlaBla.Services.svcMedication+Medication","MedicationId":11,"Name":"Name11"},{"_*type":"BlaBla.Services.svcMedication+Medication","MedicationId":12,"Name":"Name12"},{"*_type":"BlaBla.Services.svcMedication+Medication","MedicationId":13,"Name":"Name13"},{"_*type":"BlaBla.Services.svcMedication+Medication","MedicationId":14,"Name":"Name14"},{"*_type":"BlaBla.Services.svcMedication+Medication","MedicationId":15,"Name":"Name15"},{"_*type":"BlaBla.Services.svcMedication+Medication","MedicationId":16,"Name":"Name16"},{"*_type":"BlaBla.Services.svcMedication+Medication","MedicationId":17,"Name":"Name17"},{"_*type":"BlaBla.Services.svcMedication+Medication","MedicationId":18,"Name":"Name18"},{"*_type":"BlaBla.Services.svcMedication+Medication","MedicationId":19,"Name":"Name19"}]
>               }),    dataTextField: "Name",    SelectedMedication: null
>           });
>
> ```
>     kendo.bind(document.body, viewModel);
> ```